# Book series about a key that opens a door to any place you imagine

Tags: story-identification, books

There's a book series I read a long time ago about this ordinary boy who finds out he's a prince or something like that in a fantasy world.

There is a key that he is supposed to protect or something, where if you put in a door, it will open to anywhere you imagine. There is also a second key they find out about way later.

He also has powers and everyone of his kind has different powers. One person (not sure if it's the boy) can see people's  emotions by a certain aura that surrounds them. Another person can travel in time.

It has been forever since I've read the books and I can't remember the name of the series. I believe I read them sometime between 2016-2018, though I can't be sure.

I also just remembered that in one of the books, it follows a girl for part of the time and shows her going to school to figure out what her powers are. I also believe the title could be something along the lines of "the key of something" but take that with a grain of salt.

I know it is not these books from searches and comments:

1. *Locke & Key*
2. *Turn of the Key*
3. *The Keys to the Kingdom*

Comment: Might it be Locke and Key? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locke_%26_Key_(TV_series)

Comment: @Mia - Someone using a different account with the same name as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that's you, I gather you must've lost access to the account you used to post this question, and along with it, the ability to edit it yourself, leave comments within this thread, or mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You can regain the ability to do all these things by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merging your new account with the previous one.

Comment: Can you say roughly how many books there were in the series when you last read it?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts The idea of an "Anywhere Key" has been around for a while.  Another example was in [*The Lost Room*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Room), which is sometimes compared to *Locke & Key*.  (I'm pretty sure it's not this since it has nothing else in common *besides* the key that goes anywhere.)

Comment: "2016-2018" is _not_ "a long time ago"! _sigh..._

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the ***[Kilenya](https://www.goodreads.com/series/65360-kilenya)*** series by Andrea Pearson.

- Book 1: *[The Key of Kilenya](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12416944-the-key-of-kilenya)* (2011)
- Book 2: *[The Ember Gods](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12722633-the-ember-gods)* (2011)
- Book 3: *[August Fortress](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15783022-august-fortress)* (2012)
- Book 4: *[Rise of Keitus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17453351-rise-of-keitus)* (2013)
- Book 5: *[Eyes of the Sun](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19074225-eyes-of-the-sun)* (2013)
- Book 6: *[The Golden Symbol](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20750580-the-golden-symbol)* (2014)

As per the Goodreads synopsis for the first book, the protagonist, a teenager named Jacob Clark, is transported from Earth to the world of Eklaron.

> We all have a choice—but we can’t choose the consequences.
>
> Jacob Clark is chased down a path that takes him to another world—a world where he is a wanted young man. The Lorkon want to control him and the special powers he possesses. The people of the new world want him to save them from the destruction of the Lorkon. All Jacob wants is to go home, but even that choice has consequences. If he waits too long to decide, the new world and the one he came from will be destroyed.
>
> As Jacob looks for people he can trust, he finds himself in the center of a fight for freedom—both for himself and the people he’s come to know. And when he meets a pretty girl named Aloren, everything he understands about his role on Eklaron is challenged.
>
> Jacob has no idea where the path he chooses will take him, but once the choice has been made—bring on the consequences.

The plot of the first book revolves around the Key of Kilenya, one of two magical keys that enable one to go through any door, anywhere, regardless of their current location. The other key is later named as the Key of Ayunli.

> He leaned forward. “I’m going to get right to the point. Two weeks ago, an object was stolen from our village. It’s a magical key that was made hundreds of years ago, along with one other, which has also been lost. This key was created to save a princess from an evil king.”
>
> “What does it do? Open a treasure box or something?” Jacob asked.
>
> “Yes—every treasure box ever made, and more,” Ebony said. “It’s a powerful instrument. When placed into any lock and turned to the right, it opens the door—or box—regardless of the spells or locking bolts used. When turned to the left, one can go through any door, anywhere, regardless of one’s current location.”
>
> <sub>*The Key of Kilenya* (2011)</sub>

Jacob discovers that he has the power to sense other people's emotions, with each emotion being denoted by a different colour.

> Most everyone figured out he could sense other people’s emotions, and now girls—why was it always girls?—asked him for help with their relationships. “Is he still mad at me? Does he like me? What’s he thinking now?”
>
> The worst was when a girl approached him and asked what she was feeling toward him. He blushed and walked away. It had been many different colors—the ones that equaled infatuation.
>
> It didn’t matter that he’d stopped asking other students how they felt. Word spread, and he was constantly stopped by new people as he went to and from classes.
>
> The one time when this ability helped Jacob was on the court during lunch. He could always tell when people were distracted by strong emotions—fear, anger, love. He didn’t feel bad for zipping past players who weren’t really into the game.
>
> <sub>*The Ember Gods* (2011)</sub>

He later discovers another power, referred to as 'Time-Seeing,' which enables him to view events in different time periods. He's told that with practice, he'll even be capable of time-travel.

> “With practice, you’ll learn to master this ability, and then you’ll be able to take your Time-Seeing to the next level: Gussar. I suspect you’ll refer to it as Time-Travel.”
>
> “Wait—did you just say time travel?”
>
> “Of course. I’ll teach you how. Don’t try to figure it out on your own—there are many, many rules you must follow that will keep you from killing yourself.”
>
> <sub>*August Fortress* (2012)</sub>

Moreover, he discovers that his 'parents' on Earth aren't his biological parents, and that his biological father was King Dmitri of Eklaron.

> Jacob took the phone from his brother and dialed his dad’s number. He was directed straight to voicemail. “Dad, you and Mom need to come home right now. Was . . . was I adopted? I really need to talk to you guys.” He hung up and noticed the expression on Matt’s face.
>
> “Adopted?” Matt asked. “You?”
>
> “I’m sure of it—the journal is talking about a baby boy who’d been—” Everything hit Jacob at once. If he was the son of Arien and Dmitri, that meant he was royalty. He sank to the couch. A prince? Him? Then he remembered what Gallus had said when he and Akeno entered the shop for the first time. He’d called Jacob “Your Highness.”
>
> <sub>*The Ember Gods* (2011)</sub>

*The Key of Kilenya* (2011) was later rewritten and republished as *[Forsaken Prince](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36491945-forsaken-prince)* (2017), which Goodreads lists as the first book in a separate series, the *[Kilenya Chronicles](https://www.goodreads.com/series/225662-kilenya-chronicles)*. However, books 2-6 are the same as books 2-6 in the *Kilenya* series, so it appears that these two series are, for the most part, one and the same.

Since *The Key of Kilenya* and *Forsaken Prince* were both released within or before the period in which you said you read the books you're looking for, I'm unsure which of these two books you might've read.

Comment: Yes! This is it!

Comment: @Mia - Out of interest, do you recall if you read _[The Key of Kilenya](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12416944-the-key-of-kilenya)_ (2011), or the rewritten version of the same story, _[Forsaken Prince](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36491945-forsaken-prince)_ (2017)...?

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[The Keys to the Kingdom](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42967-the-keys-to-the-kingdom)*** series by Garth Nix...?

- Book 1: *[Mister Monday](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/47613.Mister_Monday)* (2003)
- Book 2: *[Grim Tuesday](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/47620.Grim_Tuesday)* (2004)
- Book 3: *[Drowned Wednesday](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/47619.Drowned_Wednesday)* (2004)
- Book 4: *[Sir Thursday](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/47618.Sir_Thursday)* (2006)
- Book 5: *[Lady Friday](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17206.Lady_Friday)* (2007)
- Book 6: *[Superior Saturday](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2049823.Superior_Saturday)* (2008)
- Book 7: *[Lord Sunday](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6657648-lord-sunday)* (2010)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keys_to_the_Kingdom):

> Arthur, a young boy, has a severe asthma attack one day as two mysterious people, one of which is called Monday, give him a 'Key', a magical artifact that saves his life, against Monday's intentions. He discovers there exists a world called the 'House', which is split into seven parts, each ruled by a 'Trustee', of which Monday is one. A divine being known as the 'Architect' has disappeared and left behind a 'Will', leaving the House and the seven Keys to her seven Trustees, but the Trustees have split up the Will and hidden the parts, intent on not letting the Will be fulfilled.
>
> The first part of the Will has managed to break free and, by convenience, chosen Arthur as the 'rightful heir' who must recover the other lost parts of the Will; this has led to Monday giving up half of his Key to him. In the first book, Arthur defeats Monday and takes control of the first part of the House. Books two to five follow a somewhat regular pattern: in each, Arthur tries to gain control over one part of the House, and ultimately succeeds after various challenges, setting free one part of the Will. Each book features one main antagonist, usually the Trustee of that part of the House, with the exception of one Trustee who wants the Will to be fulfilled but has been overthrown by the other Trustees. Sometimes, the Trustees sow chaos on Earth while he is away in the House.
>
> One important recurring part of the story is Arthur limiting his use of the powerful Keys, as using them too much will turn him into an immortal, and the presence of an immortal on Earth causes harm.
>
> At the end of the sixth book, Arthur has freed the sixth part of the Will but not yet claimed that part of the House, and the sixth Trustee is busy invading the domain of the seventh Trustee. In the seventh book, Arthur ultimately manages to free the last part of the Will, but then everything is destroyed and Arthur faces the divine being known as the 'Architect', who explains that the true purpose of the Will was to let her die and hand over the responsibility of being Architect to him. Having become the new Architect, he recreates the universe as it was, though the House will be made anew. He splits himself into the Architect and a human Arthur, whom he sends back to Earth.

Comment: No it can't be that, I'm pretty sure the series only had two keys and I don't remember anything about a 'house'